# Overlapping time and dates

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic

So I wrote this to detect overlap between numbers (time) and it worked fine, now I want to add the ability to check if its the same day of the week but when I tried to add this condition nothing is printed.

```
intervals = [[100,200, "M", "math"],[100,200, "T", "calc"], [150,250, "M", "eng"],[300,400, "W", "design"], [50,250, "T", "bio"]]
# s = start    e = end   d = day
overlapping = [ [s,e,d] for s in intervals for e in intervals for d in intervals if s is not e and s[1]>e[0] and s[0]<e[0] and d[1] == d[0] or s[0]==e[0] and s[1]==e[1] and d[1] == d[0] and s is not e]

for x in overlapping:
    print '{0} overlaps with {1}'.format(x[0],x[1])


'''
expected:

[100,200, "M", "math"] overlaps with [150,250, "M", "eng"]
[100,200, "T", "calc"] overlaps with [50,250, "T", "bio"]

'''
```

Any idea whats wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two loops are enough, to check time overlapping between two classes.

```
intervals = [[100,200, "M", "math"],[100,200, "T", "calc"], [150,250, "M", "eng"],[300,400, "W", "design"], [50,250, "T", "bio"]]

# not same object
# same weekday
# time overlap
overlapping = [[s,e] for s in intervals for e in intervals 
          if s is not e
           and s[2]==e[2]
           and (s[0]<e[1] and s[1]>e[0])]

for x in overlapping:
    print('{0} overlaps with {1}'.format(x[0],x[1]))
```

will get, (if you want to remove duplicate, will need one more step)

```
[100, 200, 'M', 'math'] overlaps with [150, 250, 'M', 'eng']
[100, 200, 'T', 'calc'] overlaps with [50, 250, 'T', 'bio']
[150, 250, 'M', 'eng'] overlaps with [100, 200, 'M', 'math']
[50, 250, 'T', 'bio'] overlaps with [100, 200, 'T', 'calc']
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a little more to Wonjin's answer to be able to account for if there are multiple class times, in case anyone is looking for this type of iteration heres my code:

```
intervals = [ [[100,200, "M", "math"],[100,200, "T", "math"]], [[100,200, "M", "eng"]], [[300,400, "W", "design"]], [[50,250, "T", "bio"]] ]

# not same object
# same weekday
# time overlap
overlapping = [ [s,e] for s in intervals for x in s for e in intervals for y in e if s is not e and x[2]==y[2] and (x[0]<y[1] and x[1]>y[0]) ]

for x in overlapping:
    print('{0} overlaps with {1}'.format(x[0],x[1]))


Output:
[[100, 200, 'M', 'math'], [100, 200, 'T', 'math']] overlaps with [[100, 200, 'M', 'eng']]
[[100, 200, 'M', 'math'], [100, 200, 'T', 'math']] overlaps with [[50, 250, 'T', 'bio']]
[[100, 200, 'M', 'eng']] overlaps with [[100, 200, 'M', 'math'], [100, 200, 'T', 'math']]
[[50, 250, 'T', 'bio']] overlaps with [[100, 200, 'M', 'math'], [100, 200, 'T', 'math']]
```